# Describing the subproblem graph for matrix-chain multiplication

Tags: algorithms, matrices, multiplication

From Introduction to Algorithms by CLRS:

> 15.2-4 Describe the subproblem graph for matrix-chain multiplication with an input chain of length n. How many vertices does it have? How
> many edges does it have, and which edges are they?

I've figured out everything except for the number of edges. I've looked at several solutions but I am having trouble understanding even those. The best solution I've found so far is [this one](https://quizlet.com/explanations/questions/describe-the-subproblem-graph-for-matrix-chain-multiplication-with-an-input-chain-bbb9033c-c916-4c4f-b2d2-17f5ab0fb7bc). I understand that every vertex has two outgoing edges for every $k$ such that $i\le k\le j-1$. One edge for $A[i...k]$ and one edge for $A[k+1...j]$. It also makes sense why we need to sum over all the vertices. What confuses me is this statement in the solution:

> ...each value $j-1=k$ can be obtained for precisely $n-k$ different pairs $1\le i\le j\le n$ (vertices).

I think the equation $j-1=k$ is a mistake and should be $j-i=k$ instead but I'm not certain. Can someone explain (in baby steps) why each value of $k$ is obtained for $n-k$ vertices?